# What happened to my exception when unmarshalling in jaxb?

Tags: java, jaxb

I need to run some validation code after my JAXB object is unmarshalled. My unmarshaller's event handler is set to the `DefaultValidationEventHandler`.

Before I added an `afterUnmarshal()` method, when my code threw an Exception, it came out like this:

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: com.example.ExceptionClass Error message
     Location: line 3
```

Now, however, I'm getting

```
DefaultValidationEventHandler: [ERROR]: null
     Location: line 3
```

My `afterUnmarshal()`

```
void afterUnmarshal(final Unmarshaller unmarshaller, final Object parent) {
    //validation code that may throw a runtime exception
}
```

Is there something I'm supposed to put into my `afterUnmarshal()` method to keep the exception details? What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

I have not been able to reproduce what you have described in your question.  Below is what I have tried.

**JAVA MODEL**

**Foo**

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    private Bar bar;

}
```

**Bar**

The `Bar` class simply contains an `afterUnmarshal` method that throws a `RuntimeException`.

```
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;

public class Bar {

    void afterUnmarshal(final Unmarshaller unmarshaller, final Object parent) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Hello World");
    }

}
```

**DEMO CODE**

In the demo code below we will unmarshal a document that will trigger the `afterUnmarshal` method on the `Bar` class.

```
import java.io.StringReader;

import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.bind.helpers.DefaultValidationEventHandler;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = jc.createUnmarshaller();
        unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new DefaultValidationEventHandler());

        StringReader xml = new StringReader("<foo><bar/></foo>");
        Foo foo = (Foo) unmarshaller.unmarshal(xml);
    }

}
```

**OUTPUT**

The `RuntimeException` that we threw shows up in the stack trace.

```
Exception in thread "main" javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException]
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleEvent(UnmarshallingContext.java:642)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.handleError(UnmarshallingContext.java:671)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JaxBeanInfo.invokeUnmarshallCallback(JaxBeanInfo.java:555)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JaxBeanInfo.invokeAfterUnmarshalMethod(JaxBeanInfo.java:546)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.Loader.fireAfterUnmarshal(Loader.java:225)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.StructureLoader.leaveElement(StructureLoader.java:271)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallingContext.endElement(UnmarshallingContext.java:506)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.SAXConnector.endElement(SAXConnector.java:156)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.endElement(AbstractSAXParser.java:606)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractXMLDocumentParser.emptyElement(AbstractXMLDocumentParser.java:183)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:353)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:2715)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLDocumentScannerImpl.java:607)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.next(XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.java:116)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.java:488)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:835)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(XML11Configuration.java:764)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(XMLParser.java:123)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(AbstractSAXParser.java:1210)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(SAXParserImpl.java:568)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal0(UnmarshallerImpl.java:211)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.unmarshaller.UnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(UnmarshallerImpl.java:184)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:157)
    at javax.xml.bind.helpers.AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.unmarshal(AbstractUnmarshallerImpl.java:214)
    at forum15142943.Demo.main(Demo.java:17)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
    at com.sun.xml.bind.v2.runtime.JaxBeanInfo.invokeUnmarshallCallback(JaxBeanInfo.java:551)
    ... 22 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Hello World
    at forum15142943.Bar.afterUnmarshal(Bar.java:8)
    ... 27 more
```

Comment: This actually is what was happening. I was using a DefaultValidationEventHandler to print out the error, and the error message was null. Our error message had gotten propagated to the level of e.cause.target, so it wasn't showing up in the console.